# Synchronization UML class diagram and Code in visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, uml, visual-studio-2013, class-diagram

I have created UML class diagram and generate classes and code, but i need to add more code in classes (new methods, members) and i need to sync my old UML class diagram and code.

Comment: So what is the question exactly? What have you tried?

Comment: I need to sync UML class diagram and code. When I add some method in code I need to this method be added in class diagram also I need when I add some method in class diagram to be added in code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use partial class for that. Write any new methods/properties in a separate partial class so that it doesn't get overridden when you sync the other partial class with the class diagram.

Partial class splits the class into separate files.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you created a class diagram within Visual Studio (.cd file) it will update automatically.

Comment: I added a method in class that I generated from the class diagram, and this method not added to a class diagram. Maybe there is a setting to sync?

Answer (score 0):

I added a method in class that I generated from the class diagram, and this method not added to a class diagram. Maybe there is a setting to sync?